# Getting System.AccessViolationException while calling a memberfunction using pointer to a class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, protocols, dereference

```
using namespace std;

class Layer
{
protected:
    Layer *lower;
    Layer *upper;
public:
    Layer(Layer *lo,Layer *up):lower(lo),upper(up)
    {}
    virtual void send()=0;
    virtual void receive()=0;
};
class Physical_Layer:public Layer
{
public:
    Physical_Layer(Layer *p):Layer(NULL,p)
    {
        cout<<"Physical_Layer constructed"<<endl;
    }
    virtual void send()
    {
        cout<<"Data send from Physical_Layer"<<endl;
        receive();
    }
    virtual void receive()
    {
        cout<<"Physical_Layer calling receive of DataLink_Layer"<<endl;
        upper->receive();
    }
};
class DataLink_Layer:public Layer
{
public:
    DataLink_Layer(Layer *p):Layer(new Physical_Layer(this),p)
    {
        cout<<"DataLink_Layer Constructed"<<endl;
        lower->send();
    }
    virtual void send()
    {
        cout<<"Data send from DataLink_Layer"<<endl;
        lower->send();
    }
    virtual void receive()
    {
        cout<<"DataLink_Layer calling receive of Application_Layer"<<endl;
        cout<<typeid(upper).name()<<endl;



        upper->receive();



    }
};
class Application_Layer:public Layer
{
public:
    Application_Layer():Layer(new DataLink_Layer(this),NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Application_Layer Constructed"<<endl;
        send();
    }
    virtual void send()
    {
        cout<<"Sending data from Application_Layer"<<endl;
        lower->send();
    }
    virtual void receive()
    {
        cout<<"Receiving data at Application_Layer"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Layer *l=new Application_Layer();
}
```

I was trying to simulate a three layer protocol stack using the Protocol Design Pattern. But while dereferencing the upper->receive in DataLink_Layer's receive i am getting a run time exception: System.AccessViolationException. Why am i getting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of `DataLink_Layer` is trying to call back into the `Application_Layer` via a `Layer*` before the `Layer` base class of `Application_Layer` is even constructed (you are still evaluating the `new DataLink_Layer(this)` at this time).

You can see this more clearly by simply calling `upper->receive()` in the `DataLink_Layer` constructor.

This [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/using-this-in-ctors.html) explains a little more about using `this` in constructors.

This simpler example may more clearly illustrate the issue:

```
struct C;
struct A
{
    A(C* c) {};
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

struct C
{
    C(A* a)
    {
        a->Foo();
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    B() : A(new C(this)) {}
    void Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

In general, you shouldn't use the constructor to execute a complicated call stack on partially constructed objects.  Just call the `send()` or `receive()` functions explicitly after construction.

Comment: But.. It works fine when i call the receive function of DataLink_Layer from the Physical_layer's receive function.

Comment: You don't call that until `lower->send()` is called int the DataLink_Layer constructor, at which point `DataLink_Layer`'s `Layer` base class has been constructed.

Comment: Is there any way to do this other than calling send and receive explicitly? Scenario is like I am supposed to send a particular data frame during the connection establishment. So i was thinking of using the constructor to do the job.

Comment: @sajas Construction shouldn't really be used to do heavy lifting like sending a data frame, especially not with complicated inheritance like this.  I don't see another way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got 1 more question. When I make the attributes in the Layer class (lower and upper) as private variables of each derived layer and try to call the virtual functions using those attributes I am able to do it. Then the correct virtual functions are called. Based on the FAQ link that you have given, should this have happened?

Comment: @sajas If you moved the data members, then the `Layer` base class will be constructed before the data members are initialized in the constructor (base class initialization is always first) because you no longer need to call the `new` before the `: Layer()`.  So I think this might technically be safe because you're practically in the body of the constructor.  Generally, if reasoning about it is this difficult though, it should be avoided :-)